# Python - manually install package using virtualenv

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I have a python program I want to install into my virtualenv - it's a zip package that I need to unzip and then run a setup.py program - but my question is more regarding how to get these unzipped files into my virtualenv so that the package gets installed into the virtualenv's site-packages folder?

I can also install from inside my virtualenv using `pip install <package name>`, but for some reason, the package that PIP downloads is out of date.

So - can someone tell me a few easy steps for installing a package manually?

So far I have the basic commands to load up the Virtualenv:

```
-bash-3.2$ source ~/.bashrc
-bash-3.2$ workon test
(test)-bash-3.2$ //Now I'm working on my virtualenv, but where do I go after this??
```

So - does it matter where I unzip the python package/program to - or should I be logged in to the virtualenv first before unzipping? After I load up the virtualenv and I'm inside using it with the 'workon test' command, will any python package I install, regardless of the directory I find it, install itself into the proper virtualenv's site-packages folder?

Option 1 is to unzip the python program into /home/username/tmp - then log into my virtualenv, navigate to that folder and run the setup.py program - assuming that the virtualenv will transfer all relevant files to it's own site-packages folder.

OR scenario 2 is to unzip the files directly into site-packages, and run it from there (after logging in to the virtualenv), etc

Thank you for helping a Python clutz with this!

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I typically would extract the program to a temporary folder, then from that folder, run the setup.py using the direct path to the virtualenv python instance.  eg if your virtualenv is in /home/username/virtualpy, use this (from your temporary folder)

```
/home/username/virtualpy/bin/python setup.py install
```

This should install it to your virtualenv site package folder.

Comment: So really the import operation is to run python using the version of python (2.6) installed in the virtualenv...nice! Thanks Dwelch.

Comment: Make sure you run it from the temporary folder; setup.py will likely expect it to be the current folder.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be necessary any longer. Once the virtual env is activated, i just run `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop` and it installs in the right place.

Answer (score 16):

well when you switch to the virtual environment. you should type

`which python`

and if it returns the path where your virtual environment exists then its okay you can directly run this command.

```
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
```

but if it gives the global level path which is not your `virtualenv's` path then you should try using

```
$ ~/.virtualenv/python-env/bin/python setup.py build
$ ~/.virtualenv/python-env/bin/python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

If a package won't install from repository, try under venv by use sudo.
As example for python pathos package;

```
/venv3.6/bin$ sudo pip3 install pathos
```

Answer (score 0):

PACKAGE_DIR=/some/package/directory/path
export VENV=$(pipenv --venv) && export BASE_DIR=$(pwd) && cd $PACKAGE_DIR && $VENV/bin/python setup.py install && cd $BASE_DIR