# pyodbc install does not support python 3.5.1

Tags: python, pip, python-3.3, pyodbc, python-3.5

I am trying to install [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) for a specific project, but unfortunately when I try to do an install, no matter the command I end up with the following error:

```
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-vw5rz5_t/pyodbc/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read()
.replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record
/tmp/pip-p5vfq2hq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-
externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-build-vw5rz5_t/pyodbc/
```

Obviously, this error has already been reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045728/pyodbc-requires-python-3-3), and I am fully aware this is a python version dependency error. However I have attempted many different approaches to deal with this issue, including all the attempts in the Stack Overflow question, and the following:

- Original attempt:

  ```
  sudo pip3 install pyodbc
  ```
- Installing in virtualenv (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979513/python-manually-install-package-using-virtualenv), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240653/how-to-install-a-package-inside-virtualenv-python))

Could anyone point me the correct way to install a python package that has a dependency on another python version than the default python package? I have another project that runs on python3.5 so I would prefer if I could do an install in the virtualenv.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960339/unable-to-install-pyodbc-on-linux

Comment: **solved try** : `apt-get install unixodbc-dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

Clone, build and install!

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc.git
$ python3 setup.py build
# python3 setup.py install
```

You might need unixodbc since it's a pyodbc dependency.

Have fun!

Comment: Change in behaviour, I get a gcc error instead - and it doesn't sound so good. I have installed unixodbc already -  `/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:52:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sql.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: Successfully compiled and installed with unixodbc-dev and unixodbc-bin installed! Thanks a bunch @marctrem
One last question: Now this is available throughout the computer? Can I run it using python3.5 from now on?

Comment: @PhilippeHebert: Can't you just try it and see?

Comment: @John Y I'll do. I'm quite new to the python environment - The only way I can see to test it with a certain version of python is to write a script that imports the module, and then run it with the python command, right? Is there any other way (out of curiosity)?

Comment: Just use the repl!

Comment: Confirmed, this works with python3.5 now!
`$ python3.5
Python 3.5.1 (default, Apr 12 2016, 08:43:33) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
>>> pyodbc
<module 'pyodbc' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyodbc-3.0.11b16-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/pyodbc.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>`

Answer (score 5):

Following marctrem's excellent answer, and the clues left by Philippe Hebert, one can easily install `unixodbc` with debian distributions using:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-bin
```

With these dependencies installed, the following works like a charm:

```
pip3 install pyodbc
```