# Virtualenv installing a package in the global directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I made sure to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979513/python-manually-install-package-using-virtualenv?rq=1) and similar ones, but I couldn't find an answer to my problems.

My problem is: when I head into muy virtual env and activate it, if I install a package there, it is also installed elsewhere in my computer.

So, for example, if I type in the terminal:

```
cd home/Documents/Python/tests/my_virtual_env
source bin/activate
```

That activates the virtual environment. If I type:

```
pip3 install wget  #just an example package
```

I see the installation process and I can run a .py script that uses wget. However, why is this package also installed elsewhere in my computer?

1. I made sure I hadn't that package installed beforehand using pip3 list.
2. I confirmed that package was installed elsewhere by running a .py script from other directories (using cd /etc.etc/ to change directory and then running it from there).

   3. I deactivated the environment in the right moment.

I also realized that if I uninstall that package within the virtualenv, it is also uninstalled elsewhere.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: When you run it elsewhere, is your env deactivated?

Comment: Run a `which pip3` to check whether your `pip3` is environment based.  You should also see a `(env)` prefix or similar in your prompts to validate your environment is activated properly.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Yes, I made sure I typed 'deactivate' beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the `pip3` command being executed is not actually tied to the *virtual environment*. So instead you could the following, which would work whether or not the *virtual environment* is activated:

```
$ path/to/my_virtual_env/bin/python3 -m pip install SomeProject
```

The following command should give you a relatively clear indication of where exactly the project has been installed, make sure it is in the `site-packages` directory of the *virtual environment*:

```
$ path/to/my_virtual_env/bin/python3 -m pip show SomeProject
```

So it should show something of the sort:

```
Name: SomeProject
...
Location: .../path/to/my_virtual_env/lib.python3.X/site-packages
```

> However, why is this package also installed elsewhere in my computer?

The following shows where a binary is located:

```
$ which somecommand
```

It should be relatively easy to recognize if `somecommand` is in a Python virtual environment or not.

Comment: Yeah, I needed to change that path first, just as you suggested. Thanks so much. It works well now :)